# Trouble Deploying Apache Doris with Docker Compose

Tags: apache-doris

I am trying to deploy a simple Apache Doris demo with docker compose.
I am using the docker-compose.yaml (Docker 24.0.5 on Debian 6.1.38-4) provided by their own [documentation](https://doris.apache.org/docs/dev/install/construct-docker/run-docker-cluster).

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
   fe:
     image: apache/doris:2.0.0_alpha-fe-x86_64
     hostname: fe
     environment:
      - FE_SERVERS=fe1:${intranet IP of the current machine}:9010
      - FE_ID=1
     volumes:
      - /data/fe/doris-meta/:/opt/apache-doris/fe/doris-meta/
      - /data/fe/log/:/opt/apache-doris/fe/log/
      - ./fe.conf:/opt/apache-doris/fe/fe.conf
     network_mode: host
   be:
     image: apache/doris:2.0.0_alpha-be-x86_64
     hostname: be
     environment:
      - FE_SERVERS=fe1:${intranet IP of the current machine}:9010
      - BE_ADDR=${intranet IP of the current machine}:9050
     volumes:
      - /data/be/storage/:/opt/apache-doris/be/storage/
      - /data/be/script/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
     depends_on:
       -fe
     network_mode: host
```

After substituting the intranet IP of the current machine with my machine's IP and running `docker compose up`, I get:

Doris Frontend Issue:

```bash
2023-11-29 14:32:55,942 ERROR (main|1) [BDBJEJournal.open():325] catch an exception when setup bdb environment. will exit.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property: je.rep.nodeHostPort Invalid hostname: fe80::8cf5:81ff:fecd:e00e
```

Doris Backend Issue:

```bash
    2023-11-29T14:37:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: BE is not register. retry.
    2023-11-29T14:37:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: this node role is mix
```

Despite this logs, it does launch the web ui, although login doesn't work, even after setting up the front-end authentication via:

```
[webserver]
auth_type = simple
auth_simple_user = admin
auth_simple_passwd = admin
FE_IP_ARRAY = 0.0.0.0

[journal]
journal_bdbje_node_host_port = 0.0.0.0:9010
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix it, i.e., log into it?